# How do I resolve "Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter"? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the [RoR Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and I'm stuck at [Listing 9.15](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-correct_user_before_filter)

I getting the following error after running **'bundle exec rspec spec/'** :

```
1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
     ArgumentError:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
     # ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:79:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My Authentication test code is:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Authentication", type: :request do

  subject { page }


  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end

    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      #it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        #it { should_not have_title(full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue so the test passes. How ***do*** I resolve it? Could someone explain what's going wrong? (According to the tutorial the test should be passing).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the end I just used:

```
root_path
```

instead of:

```
root_url
```

Comment: Did you compare your code to the [reference implementation](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4)? The code you listed appears to work OK on my system.

Comment: for me it too this answer and the answer by @AmanGarg because I had changed the url from localhost:3000 in my dev environment and I never made the same change in my test env

Comment: had same error. didn't change anything. just stopped the server and restarted it again. and it worked.

Comment: This is *not* an answer to the question and should not have been marked as such.  Please see actual answers that show how to set the default url options in your environment-specific config files.  This "answer" simply causes the url to be changed to a path, e.g. instead of having "http://cnn.com/" in your email you'll have "/".  Yes, a single forward slash.  Probably not what you want.  This is a symptom of being more concerned with "test passing" than actual problem solving.

Comment: This does answer the question "How do I resolve "Missing host link to..." when using rspec, since it gets around the need for the host. Also the other answers do not offer a resolve since it's a controller test, not a mailer test.

Answer (score 65):

The problem may be that you have not defined default_host for test environment. Define default_host inside config/environments/test.rb like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. That doesn't seem to be making any difference.

Comment: Mind to restart rails server after changing configs.

Comment: Add `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` in the end of `test.rb`. (After `do ... end` block)

Answer (score 6):

For tests like the controller tests shown in the OP's example, another setting is needed to resolve this error. Mentioned by [Kesha Antonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3452513/kesha-antonov) you can instead use the Routes' default_url_options. By adding the following setting on the last line of your config/environments/test.rb (after the **end**), your tests will use the host given to build URLs:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'lvh.me:3000'
```

As mentioned by the OP in another answer, you can instead switch to a *Path* [Named Route](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) when the error is from a URL named route.

If you want to set the default host for mailers previews, you will want the action_mailer.default_url_options mentioned in other answers.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

*See Generating URLs in the [Action Mailer API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) docs for more information on the action_mailer setting.*

Answer (score 4):

You've to set the default_url in each environment(development, test, production).

You need make these changes.

```
    config/environments/development.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

 config/environments/test.rb
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'

  config/environments/development.rb
     config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
      { :host => 'your-host-name' }  #if it is local then 'localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score -7):

You can avoid this error by using the **skip_confirmation!** method.

```
user = User.new(email: "example@example.com", password: "1234pass5678word")
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
user
```